# get assert() failure message in android ndk sigaction crash handler

Tags: android-ndk

I am using `sigaction()` to install a crash handler in my app and print private version information.

In case of a failed `assert()` the abort message is super useful and I'd like my sigaction handler to print it.  How can I get that string?  Below is some analysis I've done thus far:

I noticed in ndk **debuggerd/tombstone.c** `engrave_tombstone()` that there is a argument `uintptr_t abort_msg_address` which contains the abort message, typically a failed assert.   But no clue where that is fetched from.  Noticing the default crash logs of android seem to run in a different process and debugger**d** imples it's a daemon, I am not sure this is the right way to go.

I furthermore see in bionic **libc/stdlib/assert.c** there is just a call to `__libc_android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_FATAL, ...)`.  Also not very helpful.  But in bionic **linker_main.cpp** there is `abort_msg_t* g_abort_message = nullptr;` and other exciting stuff in **android_set_abort_message.cpp**.  Again, not sure this is the right way, feels very hackish.

This is what the crash handler of android prints by default.  Note how the first message in in the crashed pid/tid, but the others are some other random process (presumably, debuggerd?).

```
10-09 16:49:28.551 12084 12127 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 12127 (applyRouting), pid 12084 (com.android.nfc)
10-09 16:49:28.691 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_marlin/marlin:Q/OC-MR1/summit07191458:userdebug/test-keys'
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : pid: 12084, tid: 12127, name: applyRouting  >>> com.android.nfc <<<
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'jni_internal.cc:622] JNI FatalError called: applyRouting'
10-09 16:49:28.692 12203 12203 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000002f5f  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
```

Comment: You can't get that message in abort handler, it is printed to stderr before abort() is called. Can you replace assert function with a custom one?

Comment: I sure could, but the goal really was to emulate the behaviour of the default crash handler, which is able to get the message